# Is it possible to create a solar cell in home?

Tags: energy, home-experiment

I'm not really sure that this is the place to ask this question, but anyway. I'm curious is it possible to create a solar cell (not panel with 2$ cells from ebay) in home. If not why and if yes how. Thanks in in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the sort of solar cells used to generate electricity requires a [fabrication plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_fabrication_plant), and you certainly won't be doing this in your kitchen. However you can certainly make systems that generate electrity from light and there's [an example on this web site](http://scitoys.com/scitoys/scitoys/echem/echem2.html).

[Any semiconductor can in principle act as a solar cell](http://newscenter.lbl.gov/feature-stories/2012/07/26/photovoltaics-from-any-semiconductor/). The experiment described here creates a layer of the semiconductor cuprous oxide simply by heating a copper sheet in air.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I want to ask you one more question but it's to general to be asked a separate and it will get closed. Is there any way to make green energy from home. I live in place without wind and sun.

Comment: @user3395407: there are various green energy sources that don't rely on wind and sunlight. For example [anaerobic digestion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_digestion) or [geothermal energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_energy). I believe people have successfully built their own digestors, though I doubt many of us will be drilling our own geothermal wells.